# How to use MPAndroidChart's ValueFormatter in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, mpandroidchart

I'm using the NuGet package MpAndroidChart..

In java,

```
public class MyValueFormatter implements ValueFormatter {

    private DecimalFormat mFormat;

    public MyValueFormatter() {
        mFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###,##0.0"); // use one decimal
    }

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
        // write your logic here
        return mFormat.format(value) + " $"; // e.g. append a dollar-sign
    }
}
```

I tried to implement ValueFormatter, but the package does not contain an interface called `ValueFormatter`

How do I implement this in C#?

Edit:

Thank you for your answer, But how do I use this, I tried

```
QuestionFormatter formatter = new QuestionFormatter();
            chart.AxisLeft.ValueFormatter = (IYAxisValueFormatter) formatter;
```

But I'm getting Invalid Cast Exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IValueFormatter` is in the `MikePhil.Charting.Formatter` namespace

#### Using:

```
using MikePhil.Charting.Formatter;
```

#### Example:

```
public class CustomFormatter : IValueFormatter
{
    public IntPtr Handle
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public string GetFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Note: Of course you will need to implement those methods with your own code ;-)

#### Update:

```
public class CustomYFormatter : IYAxisValueFormatter
{
    public IntPtr Handle
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public string GetFormattedValue(float value, YAxis yAxis)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I use this? I tried chart.AxisLeft.ValueFormatter = (IYAxisValueFormatter) formatter; But I am getting Invalid cast Exception. please see my edit

Comment: @HeisenBerg Implement `IYAxisValueFormatter` vs. `IValueFormatter`, different method signatures, see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @SushiHangover's answer, you have to inherit from Java.Lang.Object when you implement a java interface, then the handle property and dispose method are taken care of by the base class for you and you can just write your formatting method

```
public class MyValueFormatter : Java.Lang.Object, IValueFormatter
{
    public string GetFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler)
    {
        return value.ToString("F0");
    }
}
```